# BeautifulSoup parse unstructured html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Trying to parse this html with BeautifulSoup:

```
<div class="container">
  <strong>Monday</strong> Some info here...<br /> and then some <br />
  <strong>Tuesday</strong> Some info here...<br />
  <strong>Wednesday</strong> Some info here...<br />
  ...
</div>
```

I wanna be able to get the data for Tuesday only: `<strong>Tuesday</strong> Some info here...<br />`
But since there is no wrapper div, I am having difficulties to get this data only. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this way :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="container">
  <strong>Monday</strong> Some info here...<br /> and then some <br />
  <strong>Tuesday</strong> Some info here...<br />
  <strong>Wednesday</strong> Some info here...<br />
  ...
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find('strong', text='Tuesday').findNextSibling(text=True)
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
```

**output :**

```
 Some info here...
```

**update based on comment :**

Basically, you can continue getting next sibling text of `<strong>Tuesday</strong>`, until next sibling element of the text is another `<strong>` element or `none`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="container">
  <strong>Monday</strong> Some info here...<br /> and then some <br />
  <strong>Tuesday</strong> Some info here...<br /> and then some <br />
  <strong>Wednesday</strong> Some info here...<br />
  ...
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find('strong', text='Tuesday').findNextSibling(text=True)
nextSibling = result.findNextSibling()
while nextSibling and nextSibling.name != 'strong':
    print(result.decode('utf-8'))
    result = nextSibling.findNextSibling(text=True)
    nextSibling = result.findNextSibling()
```

**output :**

```
 Some info here...
 and then some
```

Comment: Yes, but it will only include html up to the first <br /> tag, I need everything from <strong> to next <strong>.

Comment: user1121487 Your original question was what you got in the first answer "get the data for Tuesday only: <strong>Tuesday</strong> Some info here...<br />". If you wanted "everything from <strong> to next <strong>" you should have made that clear originally. @har07's original answer satisfied what you originally asked.

Comment: I think that was very clear from the structure in the example that I needed everything from strong to strong, which is everything for tuesday, since you cannot tell how many br's etc there will be. @serk